# show div when error is occur

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have validated a form.i want to show error message in a div.it has red background.i want to show it only occur a error.but my code always shows the red background div.but error message shows when error occurs.i want to show red background div and message when only occur a error.

html code

```
   <form action="registerphp.php" method="post" id="regfrm" name="regfrm"><br>

   <div class="form-group"  style="background-color: #FFBABA;color: #9F6000;border: 1px solid;margin: 10px 0px;padding:15px 10px 15px 50px;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: 10px center">
      <span id="error_message" class="text-danger"></span>
      <span id="success_message" class="text-success"></span>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
    </div>
   <div class="form-group">
        <label>phone</label>
        <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone">
    </div>
   </form>
```

jquery code

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#buttonregister').click(function () {
                 var title=$('#title').val();
                 var name=$('#name').val();
                 var phone=$('#phone').val();

                 if(title==""){
                     $('#error_message').html("Id is required");
                     alert('no');
                     return false;
                            }
                 if(name==""){

                      $('#error_message').html("Name is required");
                      alert('no2');
                      return false;
                         }
                     if(name==""){

                      $('#error_message').html("Name is required");
                      alert('no2');
                      return false;
                         }
                 });
            });
```

Comment: Two of your if statements are exactly the same. Also try using the if { } else if {} format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add

```
display:'none'
```

to diverror, next add this jquery code when an error occurs

```
$('#errordiv').css('display','block');
```

Here and example using your code

HTML:

```
<form action="registerphp.php" method="post" id="regfrm" name="regfrm"><br>

   <div id="errordiv" class="form-group"  style="display:none;background-color: #FFBABA;color: #9F6000;border: 1px solid;margin: 10px 0px;padding:15px 10px 15px 50px;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: 10px center">
      <span id="error_message" class="text-danger"></span>
      <span id="success_message" class="text-success"></span>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
    </div>
   <div class="form-group">
        <label>phone</label>
        <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone">
    </div>
   </form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
           $('#buttonregister').click(function () {
                 var title=$('#title').val();
                 var name=$('#name').val();
                 var phone=$('#phone').val();

                 if(title==""){
                     $('#error_message').html("Id is required");
                     $('#errordiv').css('display','block');
                     alert('no');
                     return false;
                            }
                 if(name==""){

                      $('#error_message').html("Name is required");
                      $('#errordiv').css('display','block');
                      alert('no2');
                      return false;
                         }
                     if(name==""){

                      $('#error_message').html("Name is required");
                      $('#errordiv').css('display','block');
                      alert('no2');
                      return false;
                         }
                 });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in your code.

1. The error div is never hidden.
2. You are updating the HTML, which actually removes the previous error messages.

To tackle these, you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Hide the error div.
  $("#error_message").hide();
  $('#buttonregister').click(function() {
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var phone = $('#phone').val();

    // Clear the error message div.
    $("#error_message").empty().html("");

    if (title == "") {
      // 2. Change below to append.
      $('#error_message').append("Id is required");
      alert('no');
    }
    if (name == "") {
      // 2. Change below to append.
      $('#error_message').append("Name is required");
      alert('no2');
    }
    // 3. Change this as well. Typo.
    if (phone == "") {
      // 2. Change below to append.
      $('#error_message').append("Phone is required");
      alert('no3');
    }

    // Use a separate check.
    if ($("#error_message").text().trim().length > 10) {
      $("#error_message").show();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use DIV of bootstrap alert as an option of custom DIV.

```
<label  for="nome" class="col-md-3 control-label">Nome</label>
<div class="col-md-7  inputGroupContainer">                     
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
        <input id="nome" type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" placeholder="Filter by...">
    </div>
    <div id="errordiv" style="display:none;" class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
        <span id="error_message_tnome" class="text-info"></span>
    </div>                          
</div>
```

and JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function(e){
    $("#error_message_nome").html("");
    $('#nome').keyup( function(e){
        if( $(this).val().length < 3 && $(this).val().length > 0  ) {
            $('#errordiv').css('display','block');
            $("#error_message_tnome").html("Tamanho mínimo 3.");
        } else {
            $("#error_message_tnome").html("");
            $('#errordiv').css('display','none');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```